# Angular Typescript Jest unit test is not failing for console errors or unknown elements

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, ts-jest

I have a jest unit test in my Angular Typescript project that will not fail if one of the components (ex. `mat-paginator` if I don't import `MatPaginatorModule` in the test's `configureTestingModule`) or template bindings (ex. `[mask]` directive from `ngx-mask` if I don't import `NgxMaskDirective`) are not found. Typically, this would fail a build, but for some reason, the Jest unit test will pass successfully.

Is there a configuration I'm missing to force these tests to fail in the build would otherwise fail?

Here's my test-setup.ts

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

getTestBed().resetTestEnvironment();
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
  { teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false } }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there was a few things going on here. First off, I was missing [some configurations for the `initTestEnvironment`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36430#issuecomment-1117801535) that were introduced mid-2022

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

getTestBed().resetTestEnvironment();
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
  {
    teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
    errorOnUnknownElements: true, // <---
    errorOnUnknownProperties: true, // <---
  }
```

This will ensure that unknown components or template errors will cause the test to fail as they would in a build. There are still some errors, though, that may cause runtime or build failures that these properties do not cover. To handle those, I created a custom override for console.error to throw an error instead of just logging it. This can be included in your test-setup.ts too:

```js
// test-setup.ts
import { failTestOnConsoleError } from './testing-utils'

...
getTestBed().resetTestEnvironment();
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  ...
);

beforeEach(() => {
  failTestOnConsoleError();
});

// testing-utils.ts
const defaultConsoleError = window.console.error;

/**
 * Forces a Jest test to fail when a console.error is detected.
 *
 * To allow the test to pass, execute {@link permitTestWithConsoleError} in your test.
 */
export function failTestOnConsoleError(): void {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  window.console.error = (...args: any[]) => {
    defaultConsoleError.apply(this, args);
    throw new Error(
      'Test was forced to fail due to a console.error that was triggered. If this console.error should be permitted, execute permitTestWithConsoleError() in your test.'
    );
  };
}

/**
 * Allows a Jest test to pass even if a console.error is detected.
 *
 * This is the default behavior and undos the logic in {@link failTestOnConsoleError}
 */
export function permitTestWithConsoleError(): void {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  window.console.error = (...args: any[]) => {
    defaultConsoleError.apply(this, args);
    console.warn('Test permitted to pass despite throwing a console.error.');
  };
}
```

Calling `failTestOnConsoleError()` in your test-setup's `beforeEach` will ensure that any test that sends a console.error will cause the test to fail. Conversely, `permitTestWithConsoleError()` will allow a test to throw a console.error and still pass, effectively restoring the default behavior.

```js
// some-random.spec.ts
describe('my tests', () => {
  it('will pass', () => {
    ... // I do not expect errors to be thrown or logged, so fail the test if they are
  });
  it('will have error', () => {
    permitTestWithConsoleError(); // I am specifically testing for an error, so the test shouldn't fail once it detects it
    myMockedService.myMethod.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      throwError(() => new Error('oh no I failed'))
    );
    ...
  });
});
```